# How to untangle master / develop when they've been merged together

Tags: git

Somehow my release branch had develop merged into it. Due to the way our system works, we don't squash the commits so I now have a tangled branch where master and develop commits go together, without a single commit to reset back to or commit.

Is it possible to untangle this without reverting each an every develop commit?

For example:

```
Master had commits
xyz
xxy
zzy

Develop had commits
aab
bbc
cba

Now master looks like: 
xyz
aab
xxy
bbc
zzy
cba
```

Master hasn't been released yet, so is it possible to untangle those develop commits from master?

Comment: You could cherry-pick the individual commits to form new branches. By the way it looks to me like you _do_ squash the commits; otherwise the branch history would not have been lost like this.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is

`git reset --hard` to the commit before all of these, and then

`git cherry-pick` the other commits in the order you want them.